# How opens differ - ExactTarget versus Sailthru

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

We moved from SailThru to ExactTarget and the day we made the switch the number of opens dropped. Does ET calculate opens differently? Does SailThru inflate numbers? Any insight?

Comment: Exact Target places precedence on the unique open numbers and I think SailThru uses total opens as the major open analytic. Both offer multiple ways to measure opens though, so you should be able to compare apples to apples once you figure out which metric equates to the corresponding metric in ET.

Comment: The thing is, we have uniques on both. Is a unique on Sailthru a unique open or a unique user?

Comment: I am not a SailThru expert, but judging from what I have seen, I would trust the Exact Target numbers more than SailThru.  Was it a significant drop? There is always a drop in Open/Delivery rate when changing ESPs. This is due to the change of at least IP address and sometimes even domain.

Comment: Not to big, just a few percent